# Unauthorized role problem to run kibana server

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-8

I am running Kibana and ElasticSearch both on localhost, but I get this error:

> [ERROR][plugins.ruleRegistry] Error: Failure during installation of
> common resources shared between all indices. Timeout: it took more
> than 1200000ms
> at installWithTimeout (F:\elasticsearch\kibana-8.11.2\node_modules@kbn\alerting-plugin\server\alerts_service\lib\install_with_timeout.js:48:11)
> at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:60:5)
> at processTimers (node:internal/timers:509:9)
> at ResourceInstaller.installCommonResources (F:\elasticsearch\kibana-8.11.2\node_modules@kbn\rule-registry-plugin\server\rule_data_plugin_service\resource_installer.js:42:5)

and a message:

> Kibana server is not ready yet

But I don't know anything about this error message. I am beginner at ES and Kibana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been faced many errors and correct them slowly, But I restarted everything from begin and do 2 things (first have done No.1 and again it did not work) and It worked correctly:

1. download Kibana and ES in same version (8.11.3), before that es was 8.11.2 althouth I downloaded them in same day and roughly in 2 hours.
2. change the username in `kibana.yml` from `kibana_system` to `kibana` and reset it's password.

I'm not sure that the second one was OK or not, but It worked instantly and without any critical problem.